# Javascript number format to number

Tags: javascript

I need to remove the number formatting of integers.

//French
1 925 => 1925

1.925 => 1925

1,925 => 1925

So, it's basically about removing the thousend separator. Numbers are only integers... no decimals.

Comment: Nothing. Regex is something I have to learn. Javascript.. I hate it!

Comment: regex isn't something that is JavaScript specific, most modern programming languages support regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to remove all non-numeric characters, then:

```
var num = '1,234'.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "1, 925 525",
    reForbidden = /\D+/g;

function formatNum(numStr) {
    return String(numStr).replace(reForbidden, '');
}

alert(formatNum(str));​
​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/5H2G2/

Comment: To clarify, that will remove a single group of one or more non-digit characters. To make it generic, probably worth converting `numStr` to a string first, e.g. `String(numStr).replace(...)` or similar so if a Number is passed it doesn't throw an error.

Comment: Thx, but a function is a bit overkill for my purpose. I only need to convert 5 integers.

Comment: Named function usage increases readability of your code. Also function makes the code reusable.

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = 123.123;

num = parseInt( 
   (""+num).replace(/[^0-9]/g,"")
);
```

But, are you sure this is what you really want to do?  1.925 gets changes to 1925, which are significantly different numbers.  If it is the case that you want 1.925 to change to 2, then 
add a `Math.round()` call, like this:

```
var num = 123.123;
num = Math.round(num);
num = parseInt( 
   (""+num).replace(/[^0-9]/g,"")
);
```

Comment: Numbers are stored in a db as just 1925. When fetched from the db, numbers are stored based on a user setting. Where I need to get the values, much later in the script, I need to convert back.

Comment: Are you saving the locale of the user so you know how to format the number later on?  And if there is any other data processing on that number, are you sure the data processing respects the locale settings?

Comment: It's a php forum software that does all this (SMF). A function fetches data like users online today and hits (page views) today. So where I need to use those values in a mod I'm making, those numbers have been number formatted, based on the users or forums settings. But I need to convert or Javascript will think 1.925 is.. well 1 point 925 and not 1925.